# Is there any detailed documentation of VerbNet's semantic representation?

Tags: computational-linguistics, semantics, reference-request, verbnet

In VerbNet, each frame has a semantic representation like this:

> cause(Agent, E) manner(during(E), directed motion, Agent)
>   !contact(during(E), Agent, Patient) manner(end(E),forceful, Agent)
>   contact(end(E), Agent, Patient)

I'm looking for a reference that lists all the possible functions, parameters and values that are possible in VerbNet. I've looked at the papers listed on the VerbNet publications page, but the ones I found that covered semantics didn't have any comprehensive list. I also saw [this](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/vn/reference.php), but it only lists out all the possible values without explanation of how they fit into the 'argument structures', and indeed what the 'argument structures' for each predicate are. Thanks!